# How can I configure the subcaption of a thin figure?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, width, subfig

I have 2 thin images. I put them into a figure using `\subfloat` from `subfig` package. The subcaption of each one has the same figure width. I tryed to solve this creating a `tabular` environment, but didn't work. How can I modify the subcaption for to be wider, like half of the linewidth in this case?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat[This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm]{%
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\label{subfig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF4sub}
}
\quad
\subfloat[This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm]{%
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
\label{fig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF5sub}
}
\caption{Short Caption}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5\linewidth}}}
\subfloat[This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm]{%
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
}&%
\subfloat[This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm]{%
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Short Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dirty trick:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat[This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm
         \label{subfig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF4sub}]{%
\qquad  % <--- added
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\qquad  % <--- added
}
\hfil
\subfloat[This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm
          \label{fig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF5sub}]{%
\qquad  % <--- added
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
\qquad  % <--- added
}
\caption{Short Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

however, there arise a question: is there some reason that you not increase width of image?

**addendum:** more elegant solution is use `subfigure` environment from  of `subcation` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm}
         \label{subfig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF4sub}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{This is a subcaption longer than 2 cm}
         \label{subfig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF5sub}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Short Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

result is (almost) the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest that you switch from using the `subfig` package to using the `subcaption` package, as the latter provides lots of options for customizing all aspects of a `subfigure` environment. Each `subfigure`'s width is set to `0.475\textwidth`, while the widths of the images are set to `2cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption,ragged2e}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=RaggedRight}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{This caption is considerably wider than the image}
\label{subfig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF4sub}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill} % maximize separation between the subfigures
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{This caption is also much wider than the image}
\label{subfig:Tomadas-de-Pressao-PF5sub}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Images and their associated captions}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```